# Table Comparison in sqlite3: Two tables intersect in date, selecting old / intersecting data based on column

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, `data_old` and `data_new`, both constructed like

```
CREATE TABLE data(
  id TEXT,
  subject TEXT,
  created INT,
  misc1 TEXT,
  misc2 TEXT,
  misc3 TEXT
);
```

`created` is in UNIX time.

When `data_new` gets populated, I want to compare the two. `data_new` invalidates `data_old` and replaces it after processing, but my end goal is to determine a) how many rows were made obsolete and b) how many rows were present in `data_old` that are missing in `data_new` where the two tables intersect in each `subject`'s individual timeframe.

So, for example, the tables are

```
data_new                                   data_old
id  subject  created  m1  m2  m3  id  subject  created  m1  m2  m3
sd  dogs     10       a   b   c
hd  cars     12       s   x   f
ht  houses   9        a   l   a   ht  houses   9        a   l   a
up  fruit    7        n   o   r   up  fruit    7        n   o   r
fr  cars     7        x   y   z   fr  cars     7        b   r   a
                                  dw  fruit    3        n   a   d
                                  gf  dogs     2        z   a   b
as  dogs     1        f   i   o   as  dogs     1        a   r   g
                                  xs  fruit    1        u   r   s
                                  ax  cars     0        g   u   b
```

My first need is to determine that in their respective subjects, IDs ax, xs and dw are obsolete, even though as was created before dw. (The subject is different, therefore it's indeterminable if dw "disappeared" or became obsolete.) So the result should be:

```
dw  fruit    3        n   a   d
xs  fruit    1        u   r   s
ax  cars     0        g   u   b
```

When I've identified and processed these, they can be deleted from `data_old` if it makes the process easier.

Then, I want to determine that gf *should* be present in data_new because older data on `subject` is present in `data_new`. Here, the result of the query should be

```
gf  dogs     2        z   a   b
```

The order of the results is irrelevant in either case.

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the desired output of the two queries.

Comment: First query - the (entire) obsolete rows, second query - the missing row. I can delete the ones from the first query from `data_old` inbetween, that's not important.

Comment: Please show the actual output.

Comment: Not clear enough? Anyway, I've added it to the original.

Comment: So you want all old rows whose IDs do not appear in the new table? And the difference between the two queries is whether any new row with the same subject and a smaller timestamps exists?

Comment: The middle section would in practice be far longer than the non-overlapping ones, with rows missing intermittently. But yes, I think that would be another way of looking at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally seem to have stumbled onto the answer. Can someone please sanity-check this?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT subject, MIN(created) AS mintime FROM data_new GROUP BY subject
) AS mintimes INNER JOIN data_old
ON data_old.subject = mintimes.subject AND data_old.created < mintimes.mintime;
```

That's... surprisingly simple if it does what I want, which it seems to at least for a test set.

Source: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: This checks whether any new row with the same subject and a *larger* timestamps exists, and ignores `id` values. I still haven't understood your description …

Comment: Each subject is really a data source. Every time I poll one, I can only look back an amount of time, without knowing what that time is. (It changes constantly and individually for each source.) Thus, the logged data becomes obsolete since I won't be able to check for missing data points further back in time. Identifying that data is the first query and what this one should do. The oldest new data point in a specific subject I can still see marks when I know that all future missing ones are bad. I can then compare the new data with the remaining log and identify holes. That is the second query.

Comment: The ID values above were pretty irrelevant, they're just the only unique value so I used them to indicate which rows I meant. Sorry for being so bad at explaining all this...

Answer (score 0):

To get all old rows whose IDs do not appear in the new table, and for which a new row with the same subject and a smaller timestamps exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_old
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM data_new)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM data_new
              WHERE data_new.subject = data_old.subject
                AND data_new.created < data_old.created);
```

For the other one, replace EXISTS with NOT EXISTS.

Comment: That works - with NOT EXISTS, it has the same result as what I posted above. However, it's far slower: `Run Time: real 15.125 user 7.795815 sys 6.637991` vs `Run Time: real 0.017 user 0.011998 sys 0.004999` compared to the `JOIN` solution. Still much better than their "correlated query" example with `Run Time: real 43.395 user 21.364752 sys 18.513186`, though. Thanks so much for your effort, seems you didn't misunderstand me after all.